# Variable junitDisplayName not found in @EnabledIf expression

Tags: java, spring, junit, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to split my unittests on a gitlab ci runner, therefore i want to annotate my parent test-cass like this

```
@EnabledIf("#{systemEnvironment['CI_NODE_INDEX'] == null || junitDisplayName.hashCode() % systemEnvironment['CI_NODE_TOTAL'] == systemEnvironment['CI_NODE_INDEX']}")
```

but i get the exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'junitDisplayName' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

but the docs say there should be such a field: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.3.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/condition/EnabledIf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out the snippets you provided to search for a fix, but could not find a working solution. To circumvent the issue, I have set up a custom [`ExecutionCondition`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.1.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExecutionCondition.html) that skips a test(class) when the display name contains the text "disabled", and used `@ExtendWith` to include the condition in the Test class:

**DemoApplicationTests**

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(CustomExecutionCondition.class)
//@DisplayName("disabled")
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("enabled")
    void shouldBeEnabled() {
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("disabled")
    void shouldBeDisabled() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Should not happen");
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ConditionEvaluationResult;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExecutionCondition;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;

public class CustomExecutionCondition implements ExecutionCondition {

    @Override
    public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(ExtensionContext context) {
        String displayName = context.getDisplayName();

//        int ciNodeIndex = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("CI_NODE_INDEX"));
//        int ciNodeTotal = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("CI_NODE_TOTAL"));

        if (displayName != null && displayName.contains("disabled")) {
            return ConditionEvaluationResult.disabled("Test '" + displayName + "' is disabled");
        }

        return ConditionEvaluationResult.enabled("Test '" + displayName + "' is enabled");
    }
}
```

I have left out the system property&hashcode evaluation to simplify the example. The condition is evaluated three times; one time for the test class, and two times for the test methods. If the class level evaluation returns false, all the test methods in the class are skipped.